# How to play a tensorflow `decode_wav()` waveform "without" IPython notebook?

Tags: tensorflow, ipython

In the tensorflow [simple_audio](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio) example, how to play the waveform without IPython notebook?

Separate loading and playing works:

```py
import pydub,simpleaudio
sndfile = '/home/roland/.keras/datasets/mini_speech_commands/left/b19f7f5f_nohash_0.wav'
#sndfile = filenames[0].numpy().decode()
sound = pydub.AudioSegment.from_wav(sndfile)
#c,w,r = 1,2,16000
c,w,r = sound.channels, sound.sample_width, sound.frame_rate
playback = simpleaudio.play_buffer(sound.raw_data,c,w,r)
```

But the waveform from tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error I found this to work:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from IPython import display
audio_binary = tf.io.read_file(sndfile)
audio, _ = tf.audio.decode_wav(audio_binary)
waveform = tf.squeeze(audio, axis=-1)
da = display.Audio(waveform,rate=r) #16000)
simpleaudio.play_buffer(da.data,c,w,r) # YES
#simpleaudio.play_buffer(audio,c,w,r) # NO
#simpleaudio.play_buffer(waveform,c,w,r) # NO
#type(da.data) # bytes
#audio.numpy().dtype # float32
#waveform.numpy().dtype # float32
```

Then I found this conversion
from the [simpleaudio tutorial](https://simpleaudio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)
to work, too.

```py
#audionp = audio.numpy()
audionp = waveform.numpy()
audionp *= 32767 / np.max(np.abs(audionp))
audionp = audionp.astype(np.int16)
play_obj = simpleaudio.play_buffer(audionp, c,w,r) #1, 2, 16000)
```